# Arrow keys on manpages & installation dialogues not working

Tags: linux, ssh, debian

I do have a strange problem in my SSH console while working on the server.
When I login to the server, I can use the arrow keys as usual e.g. arrow up for previous commands, arrow left/right for selecting the characters and so on.

But there is an annyoing problem when entering a manpage or an installation dialogue: I can't use the arrow keys anymore! Instead, the key codes (I assume) are being shown like

> ^[OA ^[OB ^[OC ^[OD

and I can't exit the manpage or installation dialogue. I therefore have to kill the session everytime :/ After googling, I found out that I have to change to

> /bin/bash

But that doesn't help.

Any suggestions?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: You can navigate up and down in man pages with the keys [j] and [k] and exit via [q].

Comment: That might be true, but the real problem is the installation dialogues which I can't use

Answer (score 1):

I don't think it's  bash problem.  What terminal are you using to ssh to the server?  Try setting

```
export TERM=vt102
```

before interactive use.

Comment: What does this command do? I tried it, but there's no effect

Comment: It sets an environment variable, setting the terminal type (which is what decides how keystrokes get interpreted).  If you connect, and don't do the export above, what does **echo $TERM** show?

Comment: It shows `xterm-color`

Comment: And what program are you using to connect via SSH?

Comment: The Mac OS X terminal, but the same error occurs when I'm connecting using the Ubuntu terminal

Comment: 11 years later this suggestion from @tink worked for me in Ubuntu 20.04 connecting with zsh in macOS 13. Thanks!

Comment: @MiB time flies like an arrow; fruit flies like a banana. *Groucho Marx*